# How to download a philippines map tiles or a philippines map for offline mapping of my application in swift 4?

Tags: download, mapbox, swift4

How to download  a philippines map tiles or a philippines map for offline mapping of my application in swift 4? I've read a lot about offline pack from mapbox , it seems like they are popular in offline mapping in multiple platforms , i've been looking for some example on how to download the offline tiles or offline map and I don't see any examples. Is there anybody knows how to deal with downloading the tiles or the map? And from where can I download the tiles or map(link or url)? Better if you give some examples. I hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 0):

This example shows how to download a region for offline use: https://www.mapbox.com/ios-sdk/examples/offline-pack/ You will need to implement your own logic to check whether an offline pack exists.

Use the [offline tile estimator](https://www.mapbox.com/labs/offline-estimator/) to see how many tiles are in the region that you want. There is a 6000 tile limit for offline packs. For more information about how offline maps work, see [this guide](https://www.mapbox.com/help/mobile-offline/).

Comment: i tried that already , and that's the problem it has a limit of 6000 tiles only